# MySQL function to calculate CRC16

Tags: mysql, sql, function, crc16

I'm working on a system that uses a large MySQL database and I need to calculate crc16 based on some columns in the table. But I can't find any function that helps me. MySQL only has crc32, but I need CRC16 / ARC.

I tried to create an SQL code to calculate how I have in Java and C # for CRC16, but without success.

Can someone help me?
Thank you!

--- Edited --------------------

The code in SQL from MySQL try...

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_crc16`(pValue varchar(255)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8mb4
BEGIN
    declare retval, b binary;
    declare c char(1) default '';
    declare i, len integer default 0;
    set retval = 0x0000;
    set len = length(pValue);
    set i = 1;
    repeat
        set c = substring(pValue, i, 1);
        set b = (retval ^ cast(c as binary)) & 0xff;
        select value into b from tbl_crc16 where idx = b;
        set retval = b ^ (retval >> 8);
        set i = i + 1;
    until i > len end repeat;
    set retval = retval & 0xffff;
    return hex(retval);
END
```

The tbl_crc16 is a list of HEX codes.

My Java and C# codes generates the same CRC16 hexa value.

Here is my implementation of CRC16 in Java for Android.

```
public class Crc16 {
    static int[] table = {
            0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
            0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
            0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
            0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
            0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
            0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
            0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
            0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
            0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
            0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
            0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
            0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
            0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
            0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
            0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
            0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
            0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
            0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
            0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
            0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
            0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
            0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
            0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
            0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
            0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
            0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
            0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
            0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
            0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
            0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
            0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
            0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040,
    };

    public static String hash(String s) {
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
        int crc16 = 0x0000;
        for (byte b : bytes)
            crc16 = table[(crc16 ^ b) & 0xff] ^ (crc16 >> 8);
        crc16 = crc16 & 0xFFFF;
        return Integer.toHexString(crc16);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: do show what you tried

Comment: and also the java and/or c# code you are trying to duplicate.  there are a number of differences in how crc16 can be calculated

Comment: @ysth my Java and C# codes generates the same CRC16 hexa value.
I need one function in MySQL to generate the same value.

Comment: It's 2020 and we're still using CRC? Why not SHA2-256?

Comment: @tadman I used the CRC16 because it is small and the hardware that will be included this hash has a limited character input.

Comment: Fair enough, though must be some really rudimentary hardware if that's the case, surely too rudimentary for Java to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implements the CRC16/modbus, without the need of using a table

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `CRC16`( _STRING VARCHAR(25)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE _myCRC integer;
    DECLARE _ord INTEGER;
    DECLARE _n Integer;
    DECLARE _m Integer;
    DECLARE _strlend Integer;
    SET _myCRC := x'FFFF';

      SET _n  := 1;  
      SET _strlend := LENGTH(_STRING) ;
      
        loop_crc:  LOOP
     
            IF  _n > _strlend THEN 
                LEAVE  loop_crc;
            END  IF;
              
            SET _ord := ORD(SUBSTRING(_STRING, _n, 1) );
            SET _myCRC :=  _myCRC ^ _ord;
            SET _m := 0;     
            loop_bit:  LOOP
                IF  _m = 8 THEN 
                    LEAVE  loop_bit;
                END  IF;
                IF (_myCRC & x'0001') = x'0001' THEN
                    SET _myCRC := (_myCRC >> 1) ^ x'A001';
                ELSE
                    SET _myCRC := _myCRC >> 1;        
                END IF;
                SET  _m := _m + 1;
            END LOOP;
            SET  _n := _n + 1;

        END LOOP;

      return HEX(_myCRC); 
 END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Query `SELECT CRC16("A");`

Returns

```
CRC16("A")
707F
```

You can check the result at https://crccalc.com/ or use your own results from java or C#

Comment: Thanks a lot @nbk! I just need to change "SET _myCRC := x'FFFF';" to "SET _myCRC := x'0000';" for CRC16/ARC instead CRC16/MODBUS.

Answer (score 3):

If you're operating on varchars, as per your function, then this will work:

```
declare retval, b, c integer;
declare i, len integer default 0;
set retval = 0x0000;
set len = length(pValue);
set i = 1;
repeat
    set c = ascii(substring(pValue, i, 1));
    set b = (retval ^ c) & 0xff;
    select value into b from tbl_crc16 where idx = b + 1; -- my idx starts at 1
    set retval = b ^ (retval >> 8);
    set i = i + 1;
until i > len end repeat;
set retval = retval & 0xffff;
return hex(retval);
```

Notes:

- my tbl_crc16's idx starts at 1; change the where condition to idx = b if yours starts at 0
- `binary` datatype that you're using for retval and b is a single byte type, that's why it didn't work; I'm using integers

[Live example via dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=709fd9082cfdce8540e65c01bdbee609), checks out with https://crccalc.com

Comment: Thanks @MarcinJ, I tested your implementation and it is correct! But "nbk" implementation doesn't use a table, I think it's faster too.